# How to publish an ASP.NET web site or web application to a file system on the command line in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

According to the answer from this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175910/deploying-to-ftp-from-command-line-using-msbuild-on-vs2012-not-working-no-error/14178916#14178916), command line publishing to FTP or file system is no longer supported in VS2012.  Nevertheless, this requirement remains for my project. I imagine other people and projects have the same requirement.

**What is a good way to do this?**

I know that at least one answer is to use [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).  That's not going to work for me.  I imagine it doesn't work for others as well.

My project already uses MSBuild on the command line.  It would be OK to add some kind of post-build event or extra build configuration called "CustomPublish" or some such.  We could xcopy the result somewhere in the post-build event.  Something like: `msbuild /p:Configuration=CustomPublish`

The problem is how to get Visual Studio to emit the final result without any "extras" like .pdb files and such.

Comment: I don't see the best reason to use command line just to publish the site. If you want there's a better or great free tools that can be used as publishing automation such as Hudson and CCNET. These technologies can publish your sites automatically whenever you commit changes.

Comment: I'm using TFS.  It has the same features more or less as Hudson and CCNET for automating builds.  It uses MSBuild though.  In the end, I'm not interested in publishing the site directly to the web site from an automated build.  I want to publish to a folder or FTP site.  If you can imagine, some folks want to carefully examine whatever comes off the build server before letting it hit a server.

Comment: so basically what you are doing is you publish your site to a folder using filesystem or FTP then either you manually or you have automated program to copy the published files and from the published files you're getting rid of the unnecessary files?

Comment: So is the publish target part if the same domain? If so after the build just have ms build xcopy the drop directory to the web server using a predefined share that only the build can use. Publish does not do more than this in the UNC case and should do what you need. I'm using this for tfs and web deployment now. Works fine

Answer (score 1):

To have MSBuild not emit the debug symbols pass the following properties via the command line:

MSBuild.exe solution.sln /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None

You could also put these values in the new configuration you mentioned :

```
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>None</DebugType>
```

I would take a look at this MSDN link as well: [Web Deployment Overview for Visual Studio and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx)