# How do I create a TFS2017 Build Task equivalent to Visual Studio's Web Deploy Publish method?

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, web-deployment, build-agent

I am trying to complete Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment automation for a web application project.  I have been helped by a series of SO posts [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457408/how-do-i-invoke-a-publish-profile-in-an-automated-tfs2017-build), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017998/how-can-i-add-ftp-website-deployment-to-a-vs2015-tfs2013-build-process), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296796/what-tfs-2017-build-task-applies-web-config-transforms-during-tfs-builds) and things are now running, except the upload to the hosting server is longer than it needs to be; I currently upload all files instead of just the ones that changed.

When creating the TFS2017 Build (or Release) there are many Task options, including some from the marketplace.  I'm referring to, in this case, the dialogue for a Build as shown below:

[image]

I'm currently using a PowerShell script which seems a little archaic and inefficient as noted above.  Do any of the tasks available to us mimic the Visual Studio 2017 Web Deploy Publish Method which runs quite nicely and quickly?  If not, what can I use for an 'intelligent' upload process that checks whether or not a file must be uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no this kind of build task could mimic the Visual Studio 2017 Web Deploy Publish Method for now.

The method trough VS IDE will dynamically check if some files need to be uploaded or not.

However through TFS build task or powershell script will not do this, just simply copy all files you assigned. Afraid there is no workaround for an 'intelligent' upload process that checks whether or not a file must be uploaded. Since we don't how VS IDE did this.

Comment: Just checking because sometimes we miss the obvious.  I am zeroing in on a PowerShell script that seems to accurately keep track of what needs to be uploaded and what doesn't.  It's not trivial, which is why I was hoping there was an existing task, but it can be done. Thanks for confirming.